# Overlay transparent mov files over JPG using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two mov files with a transparent background, say content1.mov and content2.mov. The movie files have the same size and length. I would like to use ffmpeg to create a movie which overlays the two movie files and uses some JPG, say background.jpg as the movie background. Can this be done in ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i content1.mov -i content2.mov -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=format=auto:shortest=1[bg];[bg][2]overlay=format=auto" output
```

Comment: @Ilogan This works, many thanks! One thing though, my movie files are created using the python library manim. File info reveals that the encoding software is Lavf58.45.100. Quicktime Player won't play the output mov file from your command above (it also can't play the input files). Can this somehow be remedied?

Comment: @220284 I was wondering if you would encounter that issue, but you didn't provide any output file specifics or requirements, so I made the command as basic as I could to just directly answer the question as asked. Try `"[0][1]overlay=format=auto:shortest=1[bg];[bg][2]overlay=format=auto,format=yuv420p"`. It will output a pixel format compatible with mov/mp4.